# Krita stopped working out of nowhere

Tags: krita

The message that appears in the terminal:

(my PC: Dell 5482)

```
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
libGL error: DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1' vs '23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2')
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1' vs '23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2')
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1' vs '23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2')
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1' vs '23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2')
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1' vs '23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2')
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1' vs '23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2')
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
Invalid profile :  "/snap/krita/100/usr/share/color/icc/colord/Crayons.icc"
Invalid profile :  "/snap/krita/100/usr/share/color/icc/colord/x11-colors.icc"
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (5.15.11) with this library (5.15.12)
Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue today after some Ubuntu updates. I had the Krita installed via snap (5.2.2).
When I tried to install it via apt (5.0.2) it works.
Unfortunately, I didn't preserve the user settings, so I have to set the layout and other thinks back manually.

Comment: Thank you , Man....

Comment: You can copy the configuration files from the snap version (usually `~/snap/krita/current/config`) to `~/.config/` and the stuff found in  `~/snap/krita/current/local/krita` (?) to `~/.local/share/(krita)`. The appimage version (if you managed to get it work on Ubuntu 22.04) should also use those. For the Flatpak version, it should be `~/.var/app/org.kde.krita/config` and `~/.var/app/org.kde.krita/data/krita`. Just check the file names on both sides.